# Does webRtc Hybrid app run on IOS

Tags: ios, webrtc, hybrid-mobile-app, rtcdatachannel

I want to develop IOS application using sdk like rtc.io I want to know whether javascript based hybrid application will run on IOS or not? Is there any available free SDK for IOS native webRTC Data channel app development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes there is a recent release of opensource webRTC supported browser by Ericsson laboratories, its cross platform and the first browser with webRTC support. 
http://www.ericsson.com/news/1860225

Comment: Thanks to you and thanks to Ericsson. I think Ericsson would work for me.

Comment: Tried to go this route, looks like only armv7 support, no arm64 or armv7s... so it doesn't support a wide range of iOS devices, including my iPad mini... see compatibility reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422447/what-iphone-devices-will-run-on-armv7s-and-arm64

Comment: They have good examples including a hybrid example, if you start with them you can compile them in xcode for 64-bit - https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc-examples